# Android handler and thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, handler

I'm trying to understand how Handler, Thread, Future, Callable, etc work.

So I wrote this code to simulate most common types of tasks:

```
    HandlerThread t1 = new HandlerThread("Thread di update");
    private ServiceHandler updateHandler;
    private static ExecutorService elaborateAll = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    private static Queue<Float> queue = new LinkedList<Float>();

    // ..................................... onCreate() and other code...

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            t1.start();
            updateHandler = new MyHandler(t1.getLooper());
    }

    private final static class MyHandler extends Handler {

            MyHandler(Looper loop) {
                    super(loop);
            }
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

                    switch(msg.what) {
                            case MSG_UPDATE_POS:
                                    // EXECUTOR WITH CALLABLE AND FUTURE ===============================================
                                    CalculateSeparately calcola = new CalculateSeparately(msg.arg1);
                                    Future<Float> fuValore = elaborateAll.submit(calcola);
                                    float valore = fuValore.get();
                            break;
                            case MSG_DUE:
                                    // RUNNABLE AND THREAD ============================================================
                                    Runnable snd = new MioRunnnable(dato);
                                    Thread tSnd = new Thread(snd);
                                    tSnd.start();
                            break;
                            case MSG_TRE:
                                    // ASYNCTASK ====================================================================
                                    new MyAsyncTask().execute();
                            break;
                            case MSG_QUATTRO:
                                    // ASYNCTASK WITH GET ============================================================
                                    try {
                                            float mioValore = new ChiudiTraccia().execute().get();
                                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                            break;  
                            default:
                                    super.handleMessage(msg);                               
            }
    }

    public static class CalculateSeparately implements Callable<Float> {

            int val;

            public CalculateAvgSpeed(int media) {
                    this.val = media;
            }

            @Override
            public Float call() throws Exception {
                    if(queue.size() == 20)
                            queue.poll();
                    queue.offer(this.val);

                    float spd = calcolaMediaValCoda(coda);

                    return spd;
            }

    }
```

I have tested it sending messages to it and everything works fine.

So is my code right (code, Java best practices, etc)? Or is just a coincidence that it works?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I think this code can't even compile, you use constructor "ServiceHandler" inside of class "MyHandler"

Comment: Better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: ops.. cut and paste error.. I fix it